# ContextException: Unknown Ban can't be caught (Discord Java)

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

My `unban` command sometimes throws a ContextException, when you unban a person who wasn't banned.
I wanted to catch it with a `try catch` block to notify the user that the person they are trying to unban isn't banned. This is what I tried:

```java
try {
   event.getGuild().unban(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().substring(8)).queue();
} catch(ContextException e) {
   event.getChannel().sendMessage("This user isn't banned!").queue();
   return;
}
```

But the `catch()` line just says `Exception 'net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception, in this case isn't even a `ContextException` but an [ErrorResponseException](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/exceptions/ErrorResponseException.html). Since `queue(...)` does asynchronous operations in a different thread, the exceptions cannot be thrown from here. Instead, you should use the failure callback as described by the [documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#queue(java.util.function.Consumer,java.util.function.Consumer)).

You can use [ErrorHandler](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/exceptions/ErrorHandler.html) to handle specific [ErrorResponses](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/ErrorResponse.html).

Example:

```java
String userId = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().substring(8);
ErrorHandler handler = new ErrorHandler().handle(ErrorResponse.UNKNOWN_BAN, (error) -> {
    event.getChannel().sendMessage("This user isn't banned!").queue();
});

event.getGuild()
     .unban(userId)
     .queue(null, handler);
```

The `ContextException` is only there to tell you where in *your* code the error originated from. Since the actual exception happens on other threads which give you no context to find the issue.

Answer (score 2):

ContextException handles async exception. So your try block cannot catch the exception.
You can change your code like this.

```java
event.getGuild().unban(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().substring(8)).queue(
    null,
    (error) -> {
        if (error.getMessage().equals("10026: Unknown Ban")) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("This user isn't banned!").queue();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: It is better to use [ErrorHandler](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/exceptions/ErrorHandler.html) for this.