# Java Not Catching A ContextException Error

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch, discord-jda

I was making a function to ban a member using his/her id in JDA.
I made this:

```
private void banID(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event, String @NotNull [] args) {
        System.out.println("e");
        try {
            args[1] = args[1].trim();
            event.getGuild().ban(args[1], 0).queue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Done");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("EEE");
        }
        System.out.println("E");
    }
```

But, it doesn't accept the error. I've tried removing the printStackTrace, but the error still raises. "Done", and "EEE" are not printed.
Also, it does accept every other error, but not this.
Here is a part of the error given

```
e
E
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR RestAction - RestAction queue returned failure: [ErrorResponseException] 10013: Unknown User
net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException.here(ContextException.java:54)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Request.<init>(Request.java:71)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.RestActionImpl.queue(RestActionImpl.java:197)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.RestAction.queue(RestAction.java:573)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.RestAction.queue(RestAction.java:539)
    at com.television.Commands.Ban.banID(Ban.java:56)
    at com.television.Commands.Ban.<init>(Ban.java:31)
    at com.television.CommandExecutor.onMessageReceived(CommandExecutor.java:33)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:359)
```

Comment: https://jda.wiki/using-jda/troubleshooting/#restaction-queue-returned-failure

Comment: Hi, I believe this question was discused before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285119/contextexception-unknown-ban-cant-be-caught-discord-java)

Comment: @Isma
Thanks, it did solve my problem. I'll be more careful finding answers in stack overflow next time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
 System.out.println("E");
```

after your catch block. The output you provided however indicates that the exception is thrown later on.

```
e
E
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR RestAction - RestAction queue returned failure: [ErrorResponseException] 10013: 
Unknown User   net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException at net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException.here(ContextException.java:54)at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Request.<init>(Request.java:71)
```

I guess the error is somewhere else in your Code. It does not seem to be in the part that you have shown.

Comment: But I've basically kept the whole method in a try catch block, and it is only when I execute the method. Also, the line on which the error is raised is the line in which I ban. Plus, even if the catch block is executed afterward, the "Done" and "EEE" are not printed.

Comment: Your "Done" and "EEE" are not show because the catch block is no executed. There is no error thrown in the lines "args[1] = args[1].trim();" or "event.getGuild().ban(args[1], 0).queue(). Not knowing the rest of you implementation but is there multithreading involved? ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1 seems to indicate that. I would gess that maybe event.getGuild().ban(args[1], 0).queue() is starting a new Thread and the error is thrown in there.